# Variable differential amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, analog, differential, variable

I made this scheme:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN0JDA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Gain of this differential amplifier is constant and equal to 2. I would like to have possibility to substract variable voltage but this doesn't work. Is it any easy way to make this scheme work?

Comment: Are you using a single ended power supply (0V and Vcc)?

Comment: Yes, I'm powering this opamp from 3.3V. Used opamp is BD1321G.

Comment: And what magnitudes are the signal and typical direct voltage at the input of R4?

Comment: Ranges of magnitudes on signal are from 1.65V to 3.3V. Voltage on R4 should be 1.65V (thanks to this on output will be signal with range from 0V to 3.3V) but it is hard to set this potentiometer to this voltage. Even if it succed current consumption rises by about 25mA which is way too much.

Comment: But the gain is 2, so the output is trying to go twice as big as this. The op amp Output can only be between the rail voltages: 0 and 3.3V

Comment: On negative input of opamp should be 1.65V and on positive 1.65 - 3.3V so new range after substract and gain is (1.65:3.3V - 1.65V) * 2 = 0:3.3V